# Is it possible to bulk-add docstrings to all the functions in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

I have a python project that many of the functions and classes missing docstrings.
I know that PyCharm can automatically add docstrings by the *Insert documentation string stub* command using intention action. However, for large number of methods and functions, it is tedious.
Is there a method to bulk add docstrings to all the functions at once? then I will fill what is necessary manually.

If not in PyCharm, Is there any alternative client that can do it?

Thanks in advance for helps...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer, or may be a workaround

In pyCharm,

1. goto File\Settings\Code Style\Inspections then put a tick in front of 'Missing or empty docstring' Then press OK button.
2. goto Code\Inspect Code\ then select Custom scope>>Open Files
3. You will find a panel below with your project's name, then Python\Missing or empty docstring\
4. Right click on the title "Missing or empty docstring", and select the command {Apply fix 'Fix docstring'}
5. The program will automatically add docsrtings to all functions, and classes.

This works for me,
If anyone have better solution or workaround, so please share it with us.
[image]

Comment: work in IntelliJ Idea 2018.1 ,but【Inspect Code】 in 【Analyze】